# SwiftUI onMove doesn't show reorder Controls in iOS 16 unless the list rows are off screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want onMove to work only if editing is active and onMove NOT to work through iOS 16's long press gesture on a list view row.

When enabling edit mode through a simple button, the list rows dont automatically show up the reorder controls UNLESS THE LIST VIEW ROWS ARE OFF SCREEN. Is there any way to fix this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var editModeCurrent: EditMode = .inactive
    @State private var enableMove = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            
        } detail: {
            List {                    
                ForEach(0..<200) { i in
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        CustomRow(i: i)
                    }
                }
                .onMove(perform: enableMove ? move : nil)
                .onDelete(perform: removeRows)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .environment(\.editMode, $editModeCurrent)
            .toolbar {
                editButton
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Oceans")
    }
    
    private var editButton: some View {
        return Button {
            if editModeCurrent == .inactive {
                editModeCurrent = .active
                enableMove = true
            } else {
                editModeCurrent = .inactive
                enableMove = false
            }
        } label: {
            Text(editModeCurrent == .inactive ? "Edit" : "Done")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        
    }
    
    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        
    }
}

struct CustomRow: View {
    let i: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(i)")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with SwiftUI where conditionally passing `nil` to the `.onMove(perform:)` modifier causes the reorder controls to not render properly when editMode is enabled. To disable that long press behavior, instead of conditionally passing `nil` to `.onMove(perform:)`, use the `moveDisabled(_:)` modifier like this:

```
List {                    
    ForEach(0..<200) { i in
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            CustomRow(i: i)
        }
    }
}
.onMove(perform: move)
.moveDisabled(!enableMove)
```